# Laravel validation: Call to a member function fails() on null

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

This piece of code was working a few days ago but I seem to have done something to cause it to break.

I have this route:

`Route::post('admin/routemanagement', 'AdminController@addRoute');`

Which looks like this:

```
    public function addRoute(Request $request) {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $rules = [
                'flightDep' => 'required',
                'flightArr' => 'required',
                'flightDepTime' => 'required',
                'flightArrTime' => 'required',
            ];

            $messages = [
                'flightDep.required' => 'A departure ICAO is required',
                'flightArr.required' => 'An arrival ICAO is required',
                'flightDepTime.required' => 'A departure time is required',
                'flightArrTime.required' => 'An arrival time is required'
            ];


            $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);

            if($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect('admin/routemanagement')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }
     }
```

However when this code runs, the `$validator` variable ends up null for some reason and I get the following:

`Call to a member function fails() on null`

Answer (score 5):

From the Laravel Documentation:

"... if the validation fails, the proper response will automatically be generated. If the validation passes, our controller will continue executing normally." (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

So the following code here is not necessary:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('admin/routemanagement')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

Laravel automatically responds if validation fails, and if it succeeds then the rest of your code executes normally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this default validation

```
$validator = $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
```

You can use custom validation

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ // <---
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
```