# Call to a member function fails() on array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the laravel validation.

> Call to a member function fails() on array
>
> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Call to a member function fails() on array"
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> `#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in
>   C:\laragon\www\frontine\app\Http\Controllers\authController.php:37

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $query = $this->validate($request, [
        'user' => 'string|required|unique:users|min:4|max:24',
        'email' => 'email|string|required|unique:users',
        'pass' => 'string|required|min:8',
        'cpass' => 'string|required|min:8|same:pass',
        'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($query->fails())
    {
        return redirect('/registrar')
            ->withErrors($query)
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or not but: registrar could be a miss named route.

Comment: It's the same route

Comment: Whatever `$this->validate()` is returns an array, not an object. You should check the documentation, I suspect it might return an array of validation errors (or an empty array if none).

Comment: I did the same that laravel docs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is because what the `->validate()` method returns an `array` with the validated data when applied on the `Request` class. You, on the other hand, are using the `->fails()` method, that is used when creating validators manually.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators):

> ### Manually Creating Validators
>
> If you do not want to use the `validate` method on the request, you may
>   create a validator instance manually using the `Validator` facade. The
>   `make` method on the facade generates a new validator instance:
>
> ```
> use Validator; // <------
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
>
> class PostController extends Controller
> {
>     public function store(Request $request)
>     {
>         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ // <---
>             'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
>             'body' => 'required',
>         ]);
>
>         if ($validator->fails()) {
>             return redirect('post/create')
>                         ->withErrors($validator)
>                         ->withInput();
>         }
>
>         // Store the blog post...
>     }
> }
> ```

The `->fails()` is called in the response of the `Validator::make([...])` method that return a `Validator` instance. This class has the `fails()` method to be used when you try to handled the error response manually.

On the other hand, if you use the `validate()` method on the `$request` object the result will be an array containing the validated data in case the validation passes, or it will handle the error and add the error details to your response to be displayed in your view for example:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'attribute' => 'your|rules',
        ]);

       // I passed!

     }
```

Laravel will handled the validation error automatically:

> As you can see, we pass the desired validation rules into the validate
>   method. Again, if the validation fails, the proper response will
>   automatically be generated. If the validation passes, our controller
>   will continue executing normally.

Comment: There is no need to use `$validator->fails()` [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39006734/7903663)

Comment: @GameO7er that is what I meant. As you can see in my response, I told him that you use that method (`fails()`) when [manually creating validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators). For those cases, yes you can call that method to handle the response in the way you desire. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What this error is telling you is that by doing `$query->fails` you're calling a method  `fails()` on something (i.e. `$query`) that's not an object, but an array. As stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#authorizing-form-requests) `$this->validate()` returns an array of errors.

To me it looks like you've mixed a bit of the example code on [validation hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#after-validation-hook) into your code.

---

> If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally;
>   however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the
>   proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In
>   the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be
>   generated, [...]
>   -*[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)*

The following code should do the trick. You then only have to display the errors in your view. You can read all about that, you guessed it, in... [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->validate($request, [
        'user' => 'string|required|unique:users|min:4|max:24',
        'email' => 'email|string|required|unique:users',
        'pass' => 'string|required|min:8',
        'cpass' => 'string|required|min:8|same:pass',
        'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
    ]);
}
```